# How to add a sum of numbers that end in a specific number

Tags: objective-c

First of all sorry if my English is poor.I tried searching for an answer to my dilema without any success for about two hours.I imagine this question is rather easy for you guys, but i just started out with programmin.

So using x code/objective c im trying to add all the numbers from 1 to 500 but only numbers that end in 7.For example like : 7,17,27 and so on.I only want does numbers added up.

What i have :

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int  sum = 0 ;

    for (int i = 0; i <= 500; i++) {
        if (i%10 == 7) {
            sum = sum +i;
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"Total sum is:%i", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression

Comment: You done it. What is your question here?.

Comment: Oh for some odd reason i though i did it wrong.Anyway is this the best approach i can take on the subject?

Comment: Using the formula `n * (a1 + an)/2` from above Wikipedia link the answer is `50 * (7 + 497) / 2 = 12600`.

Comment: Except for `NSLog`, is there anything `objective` about this `c` code?

Answer (score 5):

The only change I would make is...

```
for (int i = 7; i <= 500; i += 10) {
    sum += i;
}
```

This will speed up your sum by a factor of 10.

Of course, you can use arithmetic progression to get a single equation.

Comment: I'm just wondering, why is this way of incrementing - 10x faster than `sum = sum + i`?

Comment: @MorganWilde: The difference is `i += 10` instead of `i++` in the loop, so that the loop body is executed only 50 times instead of 500 times, and you don't have to test `if (i%10 == 7)`.

Comment: if it is static i would prefer `12300+((end_digit)*50)` this is the most shortest static solution.